# AngularJS select list with optgroups with selected item with combined label

Tags: angularjs

I need to make grouped list with good value and label. 
Label should be combined by label + value. 
Also one item should be selected.

My code

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedVal" ng-options="v.label as v.number group by v.group for v in list">
    </select>
</div>
```

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.selectedVal = 234;
    $scope.list = [
        {
        number: 123,
        label: "A",
        group: 'aa'},
    {
        number: 234,
        label: "B",
        group: 'aa'},
    {
        number: 345,
        label: "C",
        group: 'bb'},
        ];
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mn2nk6rb/2/

In my code:
1: values are not correct, they are 0,1,2, and I expected 123, 234, 345

2: labels should be "A 123", "B 234", "C 345"

3. no selected item...

So I recieve this code

```
<select ng-model="selectedVal" ng-options="v.label as v.number group by v.group for v in list" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
    <optgroup label="aa">
        <option value="0">123</option>
        <option value="1">234</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="bb">
        <option value="2">345</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

And I expect for

```
<select ng-model="selectedVal" ng-options="v.label as v.number group by v.group for v in list" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <optgroup label="aa">
        <option value="123">A 123</option>
        <option value="234" selected>B 234</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="bb">
        <option value="345">C 345</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Please help!

UPD:
Also I need to serialize my form with jQuery. So I very need good values in options.

Here is updated fiddle with submit
http://jsfiddle.net/uwozaof9/2/

Answer (score 7):

Forked your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/uwozaof9/1/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedVal" ng-options="v.number as (v.label + v.number) group by v.group for v in list">
    </select>
    {{selectedVal}}
</div>
```

if you want to serialize your form, you can use track by option. Check

http://jsfiddle.net/uwozaof9/5/

but then you won't be able to set your model.

More more information check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions.

> Using select as will bind the result of the select expression to the
>   model, but the value of the  and  html elements will
>   be either the index (for array data sources) or property name (for
>   object data sources) of the value within the collection. If a track by
>   expression is used, the result of that expression will be set as the
>   value of the option and select elements.

Comment: Thanx!But values still 0,1,2  rather than 123,234,345.
I posted an exampled that I need above

Comment: have you checked my fiddle? Values are 123, 234, 345

Comment: Problem is - I want to serialize my form with jQuery on submit.
Look for my update with submit
http://jsfiddle.net/uwozaof9/2/

Comment: Sorry. I thought that it will be anough )

Comment: Now there is no selected item )

Comment: That' why I made a comment also, check out link I have provided for more info

Comment: Thank you! Also I posted my own answer

Answer (score 3):

Temporary I made a hook with hidden input

This is example that works

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<form id="aaa" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="hidden" name="select" value="{{selectedVal}}">
    <select ng-model="selectedVal" ng-options="v.number as (v.label + v.number) group by v.group for v in list">
    </select>
    {{selectedVal}}
    <button ng-click="go()">go</button>
</form>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope, $element) {

    console.log($('form'))

    $scope.selectedVal = 234;
    $scope.list = [
        {
        number: 123,
        label: "A",
        group: 'aa'},
    {
        number: 234,
        label: "B",
        group: 'aa'},
    {
        number: 345,
        label: "C",
        group: 'bb'},
        ];

        $scope.go = function(form){
           console.log($('form#aaa').serializeArray());
        }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uwozaof9/4/

Comment: It is bad practice to write dom into controller. It will make your controller hard to test and reusable.

Comment: Ok, in my case I use $element.serialize(). Is it ok?

Comment: $element.serialize() is nothing but a dom manipulation. If you have studied angular properly, then you must be knowing that all DOM part should go to directives only. That's why we have directives in angular or any other frameworks.